# Prove or disprove $n^2+41n+41$ is a prime number for every integer $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Prove or disprove $n^2+41n+41$ is a prime number for every integer $n$

I started with the base step:

$n(0) = 0^2+41(0)+41 = 41$

But I have no idea how to proceed in proving this.  Any tips or suggestions on getting start with this are appreciated.

Comment: $n(41)$ looks pretty not-prime to me.

Comment: @MikeMiller, thanks for that hint!  But how would I have figured that out without trying every number from $0-41$?

Comment: ...by observing that each coefficient except the first is a multiple of 41.

Comment: @vadim123, I'm sorry, I'm slow so please bear with me.  I'm just not seeing what you are saying.  $41^2+41(41)+41=3403$  How do we know this number is not prime?

Comment: $41$ is a divisor of the number. in other words you can write what you had as $41(41+41+1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no non-constant polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that is able to take only prime values on $\mathbb{Z}$.

The reason is that:
$$ (b-a)\mid (p(b)-p(a)), $$
so, assuming that $p(a)=p_i$, then $p_i\mid p(a+kp_i)$ for every $k\geq 1$.

Assuming now that $p(a+kp_i)$ is a prime, it must be $\pm p_i$, so $p\pm p_i$ has an infinite number of integer roots, hence it is constant.

Comment: As a slightly related problem, if a polynomial in $Z[x]$ has a range containing all primes it is $x$.

Comment: @JorgeFernández Surely you need more constraints than that, as $x+c$ also works for any integer $c$.

Comment: oh crap, well, it is $x+c$ or $-x+c$.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, if you let $n = 41$ then $(41)^2 + 41(41) + 41 = 3403$. Thus $3403$ can be factor in  two other numbers $41$ and $83$. Therefore this statement is not true for all $n \in Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight alteration to Jack's response, suppose $p$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb Z$. Then if $p(a)$ is a multiple of $n$ so is $p(a+kn)$ for every integer $k$ since $a+kn\equiv a\bmod n$. Since a polynomial cannot take on the same value infinite times there must be a value say $b$ for which $p(b)$is a proper multiple of $n$. Using this we can prove any non-constant polynomial has an element with as many numbers in its prime factorization as is required.

Comment: For some reason this explanation really made this hit home for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, for $n\equiv0 \mod(41)$, this term is product of two or three numbers, therefore not a prime.

Comment: what do you mean for $n\bmod 41$?

Comment: I mean $n=41k$ My latex is not the best. I mean n congruent 0 modulo 41

Comment: oh ,I see it can be the product of more than three numbers though.

Comment: Thank you Jorge Fernandez